# Differences between Node.js and React.js applications

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a section of code in javascript that looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var subscriptions = []

var array = fs.readFileSync('optimal.csv', 'utf8').toString().split("\r");
for (i in array) {
    stock = array[i].split(':')[0];
    if (stock)
        subscriptions.push(stock)
}
```

When I say:

```
node .\realtime.js
```

it has no problem reading the file 'optional.csv'.

However, if I copy the same section of code to a `react.js` application built with `create-react-app` and try to run it, I get errors:

```
TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
```

when I run it thus:

```
npm run start

var fs = require('fs');

// Grid data as an array of arrays
const quoteList = [];
var i = 0;
var stock;

var array = fs.readFileSync('optimal.csv').toString().split("\r");
    for (i in array) {
        stock = array[i].split(':')[0];
        if (stock)
            quoteList.push(stock)
    }
```

- **What is the correct way to read a `.csv` file from a purely react application?**

Comment: It's because `react` !== `node`. Node is working on the server side, when React on the client.

Comment: Right, but I thought they were both javascript. Why doesn't something as simple as reading a file not work from both!?!!

Comment: My guess is that node is a server side technology while react is client side. Still, reading files are needed from both.

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769051/how-to-upload-and-read-csv-files-in-react-js

Answer (score 1):

`fs` is a module implemented by `node.js` which is not provided by `javascript` itself. Maybe other environments provide `fs` as well, but `react` is just a module like `fs`, rather than another environment, so it can not provide extra module

Another thing, `react` code run in browser, where you expect `fs` refer to? Read every user's file system?

If you want to read your local csv file. You can use some bundler like Webpack which can bundle csv file into your output Javascript file. If reading **local** csv is what you want, you can do some thing like

`const csv =require('/path/to/csv')`

Maybe you need some plugin, because `create-react-app` may not provide the csv loader

Here are the steps to get a `json` from the csv file

1. `npm run eject` in the project root
2. `npm install --save dsv-loader`
3. open `webpack.config.dev.js` under `config`
4. under `module>loaders>exclude(line 110)` add `/\.csv$/` in the list
5. add `{test: /\.csv$/,loader: 'dsv-loader'}` entry in `module>loaders`
6. re-run `npm start`
7. `require('path/to/csv')` will return json
8. do the same thing on `webpack.config.prod.js` if you need the production bundle

Comment: Thanks. While this is helpful, it is insanely hard to read a text file from the local drive using react. I did as you suggest const csv =require('/path/to/csv'), but then how do I read the lines, one by one?

Comment: @Ivan OK, I will figure it out for you, follow the instruction in the updated answer, you will get a json parsed from csv