# How to read from a csv file in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, csv

I built a super basic react app using the typescript version of create-react-app.

In my react app I want to display data from `csv` files I have added my project. Imagine a `data.csv` file under `src`.

On a button click I want to trigger a function that reads this file, uses some of the data for calculations etc and then prints the result. What's the best way to make this happen? I know how to trigger a function on button click in React but don't know what to do within that function to read the file and console log the data to start.

**Important** - I already have the file path and file in my project and do not need user input to find the file

I tried using things like fs within the function but those throw errors and I learnt its because they are native modules and cant be used on browser. So what can be used for browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload and read CSV files in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769051/how-to-upload-and-read-csv-files-in-react-js)

Answer (score 4):

`fs` only works on the server, not on the client. The browser doesn't have (general) access to the file system.

There are several options:

#### 1. public folder

Put the .csv file into the `public` folder, then you can load it like:

```
function App() {
    const [ text, setText ] = useState();

    const load = function(){
        fetch( './csvInPublicFolder.csv' )
            .then( response => response.text() )
            .then( responseText => {
                setText( responseText );
            })
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ load }>load</button>
            <h2>text:</h2>
            <pre>{ text }</pre>
        </div>
    );
}
```

#### 2. webpack file-loader

Or, if the file has to be inside the `src` folder,

- install: `yarn add file-loader --dev`
- add a `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.csv$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

- And import the csv file like:

```
import csvFilePath from './csvInSrcFolder.csv';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [ text, setText ] = useState();

    const load = function(){
        fetch( csvFilePath )
            .then( response => response.text() )
            .then( responseText => {
                setText( responseText );
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ load }>load</button>
            <h2>text:</h2>
            <pre>{ text }</pre>
        </div>
    );
}
```

#### 3. server

Or you can create a custom server.js and send a request to the server. On the server you have access to the file system (`fs`).

#### 4. parse csv

if you don't want to parse the file content yourself, you can use an existing csv parser. Some people recommend [papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse) *(I don't have own experience about which ones are good)*

```
import * as Papa from 'papaparse';
// ...
fetch( csvFilePath )
    .then( response => response.text() )
    .then( responseText => {
        // -- parse csv
        var data = Papa.parse(responseText);
        console.log('data:', data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since OP mentioned:

> **Important** - I already have the file path and file in my project and do not need user input to find the file

it will be better to pre-read the file and have its content available already in the app. This will avoid the need of doing any `fetch` at run time and will improve the performance.
To do this, we'll have to configure `webpack`.

This can be done in the following way:

1. Install `react-app-rewired` so that we can modify `webpack.config.js`.
2. Have a rule added to `webpack.config.js` (indirectly, via the above package) for loading the content of the `csv` file when we run `npm start` or `npm run build`.
3. Import the `csv` file in the React component script and use its content.

Explained in detail below.

---

### 1. Install `react-app-rewired`

Check the documentation here - https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired.
Basically, we have to:

1. `npm install react-app-rewired@1.6.2 --save-dev`
2. flip the `start`, `build`, `test` commands in `package.json` like this:

   ```json
   - "start": "react-scripts start",
   + "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   ```

### 2. Create and Update `config-overrides.js`

Create a file called `config-overrides.js` in the project's root directory, and add there:

```js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.module.rules = [
    ...config.module.rules,
    {
      resourceQuery: /raw/,
      type: 'asset/source',
      generator: { emit: false, }
    },
    {
      test: /\.csv$/,
      loader: 'csv-loader',
      type: 'asset/source',
      options: {
        dynamicTyping: true,
        header: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true
      },
      generator: { emit: false }
    } 
  ]
  return config;
}
```

**Note**: The first rule above will help us read the file as plain text, while the next one will parse it for us (provided we have installed `csv-loader`).
Use whichever is required as per the need.

### 3. Import `csv` file in React script

```js
const csv = require('./filename.csv?raw'); // we get string
// or
const csv = require('./filename.csv'); // we get json
// Use the csv variable wherever needed
```